# Numbered section hidden from the ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, indentation, appendices

I'm writing a set of course notes that has an appendix containing many activities.

I do not wish the activities to be shown in the Table of Contents, but I do wish them to be numbered. Here is the solution I was using:

In the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\activity}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
```

and now my "activity" starts out with:

```
\newpage
\activity\section{A Fun Educational Activity}
```

There is only one problem. The activity starts out indented, as opposed to not indented, as a section should be.

How do I make my activity start out without an indent?

I realize I could simply add `\noindent` but it seems to me that there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adjust the `tocdepth` counter, but only for the appendix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{bla}

\section{blubb}

\appendix 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\section{foo}

\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: The `tocdepth` counter stands for *"[t]he level number of the least significant sectional unit listed in the table of contents"* (Lamport, *LaTeX: A document preparation system*, p. 176). Its default value is 3 for the `article` class (i.e., everything down to `\subsubsection` will make it into the ToC), 2 for `book` and `report`.

EDIT2: Stefan correctly points out in his answer that *"[m]odifying `tocdepth` within the table of contents may affect the following list of tables or list of figures, if present"*. Here's a solution that doesn't involve using additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\section{bla}

\section{blubb}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
(Figure content)
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\appendix 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\section{foo}

\section{bar}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
(Figure content)
\caption{An appendix figure}
\end{figure}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 5):

Modifying `tocdepth` within the table of contents may affect the following list of tables or list of figures, if present.

The package [tocvsec2](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) provides ways for changing the depth of the TOC within the document body. For example, use

```
\maxtocdepth{section}
```

at the beginning of the document and

```
\settocdepth{part}
```

at the beginning of the appendix.